# Why i can't get 3D mol structure in RDkit?

Tags: rdkit

I have edited the molecule as I wanted. Now I have to export it. But mol blocks always look 2D. So my molecules become 2D. I want to get a 3D structure. Does anyone know the solution? (look at the image for the screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found the solution. I added AllChem.EmbedMolecule(m4, useRandomCoords=True , randomSeed=0xf00d) random coords commmand and embed function returned 0. Problem was the molecule. It is so big. Thank you for your effort my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No issues with the code as below (version 2021.03.3):

```py
m_smiles = 'c1ccccc1'
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(m_smiles)
mol = Chem.AddHs(mol)

AllChem.EmbedMolecule(mol, randomSeed=0xf00d)
print(Chem.MolToMolBlock(mol))

...


     RDKit          3D

 12 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   -0.2995   -1.3510    0.0141 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.3055   -0.4032    0.0428 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.0307    0.9497    0.0294 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.3037    1.3426   -0.0142 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.2985    0.3934   -0.0425 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.0206   -0.9630   -0.0291 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.5031   -2.4015    0.0241 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -2.3381   -0.7237    0.0766 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.8299    1.6790    0.0523 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.5056    2.4116   -0.0242 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.3290    0.7220   -0.0763 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.8494   -1.6559   -0.0530 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  2  0
  2  3  1  0
  3  4  2  0
  4  5  1  0
  5  6  2  0
  6  1  1  0
  1  7  1  0
  2  8  1  0
  3  9  1  0
  4 10  1  0
  5 11  1  0
  6 12  1  0
M  END
```

Some things to check:

Check if the embed function returns a non-zero exit status, it is possible that the function failed to embed your molecule

```py
result = AllChem.EmbedMolecule(mol, randomSeed=0xf00d)
assert result != 0
```

Check if the conformer is marked as 3D

```py
result = AllChem.EmbedMolecule(mol, randomSeed=0xf00d)
c = mol.GetConformer()
print(c.Is3D())
...
True
```

Print the coordinates of the conformer

```py
result = AllChem.EmbedMolecule(mol, randomSeed=0xf00d)
c = mol.GetConformer()
print(c.GetPositions())
...
[[-0.29949394 -1.35098866  0.01410225]
 [-1.30551208 -0.40318505  0.04275071]
 [-1.03072469  0.949724    0.02942649]
 [ 0.30371624  1.34255959 -0.01420523]
 [ 1.29846541  0.39342702 -0.04249222]
 [ 1.02064112 -0.96295912 -0.02906111]
 [-0.50308026 -2.40153594  0.0241313 ]
 [-2.33811252 -0.72370675  0.07656442]
 [-1.82994742  1.67895926  0.0522682 ]
 [ 0.50563305  2.41164485 -0.02424598]
 [ 2.32904788  0.72199377 -0.07627234]
 [ 1.8493672  -1.65593298 -0.05296649]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer my friend. My embed function returns -1 I think it is the problem. May the problem comes from my SMILES string? Because at the image above begining of the string is SMILES but then continues as SMARTS string. If this is not the problem, what it may be?

Comment: Can you share the SMILES string?

Comment: I found the solution. I added AllChem.EmbedMolecule(m4, useRandomCoords=True , randomSeed=0xf00d) random coords commmand and embed function returned 0. Problem was the molecule. It is so big. Thank you for your effort my friend.